# Self join with aggregate function or some better way

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using `SQL-Server` and have a table of my **Purchase orders (stock)**. But stuck in a query while I was trying to get my **All Available** stock with its **Latest Cost Price** and **Latest Selling Price**.

I made a query it run successfully, but i need some better and optimized way to do this, because it will get slow when table have `n` number of records.

**Query Sample:**

```
SELECT 
    po.ProductID, sum(po.AvailableQty) as AvailableQty,
    (select top 1 po2.CostPrice from Sales_PurchaseOrders po2 where po2.PurchasedAt=max(po.PurchasedAt)) as CostPrice,
    (select top 1 po2.SellingPrice from Sales_PurchaseOrders po2 where po2.PurchasedAt=max(po.PurchasedAt)) as SellingPrice
FROM 
    Sales_PurchaseOrders po
INNER JOIN Sales_Products p on p.ProductID=po.ProductID
GROUP BY po.ProductID
```

**Table Data:**

```
PurchaseOrderID ProductID   CostPrice                               SellingPrice                            AvailableQty                            PurchasedAt
--------------- ----------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- -----------------------
1               1           90.000000                               100.000000                              2.000000                                2016-07-28 00:00:00.000
2               1           33.580000                               50.000000                               0.000000                                2016-06-28 00:00:00.000
3               2           200.000000                              240.000000                              15.000000                               2016-07-30 00:00:00.000
4               1           50.000000                               60.000000                               0.000000                                2016-08-02 00:00:00.000
5               1           50.000000                               60.000000                               1.000000                                2016-08-03 00:00:00.000
6               1           100.000000                              110.000000                              6.000000                                2016-08-04 00:00:00.000
7               1           25.000000                               30.000000                               3.000000                                2016-08-03 00:00:00.000
8               1           20.000000                               30.000000                               0.000000                                2016-07-30 00:00:00.000
1007            1           100.000000                              200.000000                              2.000000                                2016-09-24 00:00:00.000
```

**Query Result:**

```
ProductID   AvailableQty                            CostPrice                               SellingPrice
----------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1           14.000000                               100.000000                              200.000000
2           15.000000                               200.000000                              240.000000
```

May be via some kind of aggregate function, or any other better optimized way to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I'm not sure that your query really does what you might think it is doing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff please review now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT po.ProductID, sum(po.AvailableQty) as AvailableQty,
       MAX(last_CostPrice), MAX(last_SellingPrice)
FROM (SELECT po.*, 
             FIRST_VALUE(CostPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY PurchasedAt DESC) as last_CostPrice,
             FIRST_VALUE(SellingPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY PurchasedAt DESC) as last_SellingPrice
      FROM Sales_PurchaseOrders po
     ) po
GROUP BY po.ProductID;
```

Notes:

- The table `Sales_Products` seems totally unnecessary for the query.
- You probably want the most recent cost and selling price for the *product*, not for all products.
- You can  use `FIRST_VALUE()` in the subquery to get this information.

Comment: Getting error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'`

Comment: @Mehmood - the syntax in gordon's query looks fine, are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like a bit of `with` clause. But as i mentioned I need some optimized query, and I will be thankful if you describe it a little more, that how its more optimized?

Answer (score 1):

Dear Mehmood Try this.

```
;with wt_table 
as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by po.ProductID order by PurchasedAt desc) as Num,
AvailableQty=sum(po.AvailableQty) over(partition by po.ProductID),
po.ProductID,
po.CostPrice,
po.SellingPrice,
po.PurchasedAt
From    #Sales_PurchaseOrders po)
select * from wt_table  where Num=1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with Sales_PurchaseOrders(PurchaseOrderID,ProductID,CostPrice,SellingPrice,AvailableQty,PurchasedAt)AS(
select 1,1,90.000000,100.000000,2.000000,'2016-07-28 00:00:00.000' union all
select 2,1,33.580000,50.000000,0.000000,'2016-06-28 00:00:00.000' union all
select 3,2,200.000000,240.000000,15.000000,'2016-07-30 00:00:00.000' union all
select 4,1,50.000000,60.000000,0.000000,'2016-08-02 00:00:00.000' union all
select 5,1,50.000000,60.000000,1.000000,'2016-08-03 00:00:00.000' union all
select 6,1,100.000000,110.000000,6.000000,'2016-08-04 00:00:00.000' union all
select 7,1,25.000000,30.000000,3.000000,'2016-08-03 00:00:00.000' union all
select 8,1,20.000000,30.000000,0.000000,'2016-07-30 00:00:00.000' union all
select 1007,1,100.000000,200.000000,2.000000,'2016-09-24 00:00:00.000'
)
select * from (
    SELECT 
po.ProductID, sum(po.AvailableQty)over(partition by po.ProductID) as AvailableQty,CostPrice,SellingPrice,
row_number()over(partition by po.ProductID order by po.PurchasedAt desc) as seq
    FROM  Sales_PurchaseOrders  po

) as t where t.seq=1
```

```
    ProductID   AvailableQty    CostPrice   SellingPrice    seq
1   1   14,000000   100,000000  200,000000  1
2   2   15,000000   200,000000  240,000000  1
```